# Trying to Prepare a Statement To Store In Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Ok. I have a form with two input fields. One is to capture the date, the other is a text field for the "goal title". I have button to click to add another "goal title" field when pressed. On form submission, there will be anywhere between 2 and 21 entries.

(There will be one single date entry that will apply to all "goal titles" and as many as 20 "goal titles".

The html for the form looks like this:

```
<form action="handlers/add-goals.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Add Goals</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="assigned_by_user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="assign_to_user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>What Date Are You Adding Goals For?</label>
        <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="due_date" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Goal #1:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="goal_title" required>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add Another Goal Area" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Add Goal(s)">
</form>
```

Then we have the javascript that looks like this:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 20;
function addInput(divName){
 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='form-group'><label>Goal # " + (counter + 1) + "</label><input class='form-control' type='text' name='goal_title' required></div>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
 }
}
```

Finally, the PHP form that it is submitting to is:

```
<?php

include('../../includes/db_con.php');
$due_date = $_POST['due_date'];
$date_assigned = date("Y-m-d");

$goal_titles = $_POST['goal_title'];


if($due_date<$date_assigned) {
    echo '<script> alert("Sorry. You can not make a goal due before today\'s date!"); </script>';
    echo '<script> window.location.href="../add-goal.php"; </script>';
}
else {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO goals (title, instructions, belongs_to, assigned_by, due_date, date_assigned, completed, completed_on, deleted, notes) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") or die("Error: " . $con);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($goal_titles); $i++) {
        $title = $goal_titles[$i];
        $instructions = '';
        $assigned_by_user_id = $_POST['assigned_by_user_id'];
        $assigned_to_user_id = $_POST['assign_to_user_id'];
        $due_date = $_POST['due_date'];
        $date_assigned = date("Y-m-d");
        $completed = 'NO';
        $completed_on = '';
        $deleted = '0';
        $notes = '';
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss', $title, $instructions, $assigned_to_user_id, $assigned_by_user_id, $due_date, $date_assigned, $completed, $completed_on, $deleted, $notes);

        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $stmt->close();
    echo '<script> alert("Added to your goals!"); </script>';
    echo '<script> window.location.href="../add-goal.php"; </script>';
}


?>
```

What I am experiencing is the php script is storing the last "goal_title" row to the database instead of all of them and it is only capturing the first letter of that "goal_title".

I'm assuming my error is in the php script but included everything so you can see all that is going on.

Comment: You'll need to send arrays of data using form names with square brackets like `name="goal_title[]"`

Comment: Well, I'll be. ;) Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, you need to send an array of `goal_title` data. You tell PHP that the data is an array by adding square brackets to the form element `name` attribute. For example

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Goal #1:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="goal_title[]" required>
</div>
```

and in your JS

```
...<input class='form-control' type='text' name='goal_title[]' required>...
```

---

An extra thing to note is that statements only need to be prepared **and bound** once. The variables used in `bind_param` are passed by reference so their values may be changed.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO goals (title, instructions, belongs_to, assigned_by, due_date, date_assigned, completed, completed_on, deleted, notes) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$instructions = '';
$assigned_by_user_id = $_POST['assigned_by_user_id'];
$assigned_to_user_id = $_POST['assign_to_user_id'];
$due_date = $_POST['due_date'];
$completed = 'NO';
$completed_on = '';
$deleted = '0';
$notes = '';

// note that $title may be unassigned at this point
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $title, $instructions, $assigned_to_user_id, $assigned_by_user_id, $due_date, $completed, $completed_on, $deleted, $notes);

foreach($goal_titles as $title) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother. That was definitely it.